# SU question 473143 has two accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, accepted-answer

The question [How to tab between buttons on an Mac OS X dialog box](https://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box), recently migrated from SO to SU, has the interesting sight of two accepted answers. Even if this is a case of a merge (which is not documented on the page), surely the checkmark should only be shown for the answer accepted by *this* question's author.

Comment: That's funny :)

Comment: This kind of issue was reported here on meta before too,[Two accepted answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127792/173001)

Comment: @Lucifer looks like it must be different causes since this happens after a refresh

Comment: @BenBrocka, but both the sites are different. The case has not repeated to S.O. but this is first time for Superuser site.

Comment: This is not the first time it's happened on SU @luc

Comment: I think this may be the highest upvote *rate* of any of my posts...

Comment: Interesting case; the tooltips on the two checkmarks differ (the second one adds a date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ancient bug in migrations (I think we're on revision 8 on that) smashed that particular post, I've fixed up the data.

Comment: And now the wrong one is pinned to the top. :)

Comment: @Mysticial it'll fix itself in a minute.

Comment: Looks like it's already fixed. :)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is an ancient bug (and probably long-ago fixed so new posts can't cause this anymore), but it's bizarre

The SO question was one of the first posts, and the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2381/timeline) shows that it's always had two accepted answers, with no unaccept. The first one is the one recorded in the data dump as the actual accepted answer. The SU migration [automatically unaccepted](https://superuser.com/posts/473143/timeline) the second one, but both posts are still showing up with checkmarks, and the supposed unaccepted one is the one getting credit ([this](https://superuser.com/users/5257/rufo-sanchez?tab=answers) versus [this](https://superuser.com/users/674/ruddzw?tab=answers))

The way the database schema is set up, only one post can actually be accepted, so the double checkmark has to be generated some other way. It looks like https://superuser.com/a/473144/36115 is the one that's actually accepted