# Question 72394 has two accepted answers

Tags: bug

The following question has two accepted answers. It appears that the one with fewer votes somehow became undeleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

**Related**

- [SU question 473143 has two accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147004/su-question-473143-has-two-accepted-answers)

Comment: Well, with +1200 votes, that's the community accepting the vote, right? I'm sure this feature has been requested before, didn't recall it being implemented though.

Comment: @Oded No, this is a likely just a migration edge case. The question was migrated away to ProgSE, then the migration was rejected and it got bumped back. I believe accepted answers are preserved, so it ended up with two.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Guess I should be clearer when joking, now that I have a ♦...

Comment: @Oded Nah, it's funnier if people have to wonder. ;)

Comment: They have these things called emoticons.  There's also end tags, such as `</kidding>`, `</irony>` and `</snark>` that can be used.

Comment: I see what you did there, @RobertHarvey

Comment: Well, the question itself is currently unlocked and **open** on Programmers. Seems like an issue. I thought this wasn't supposed to happen. One of them should be deleted.

Comment: Heh. Migration was rejected 1 year and 5 months after migration.

Comment: @animuson: Why?  There's no such thing as a cross-site duplicate, and Programmers and SO have different site scopes.  We could decide that the post should live on only one site, but note that the content is not identical between the two posts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because you're providing the exact same question in two different places with two different versions of information.

Comment: @Oded: Perhaps the same migration rules should apply to rejections. Don't allow rejections to occur if the question has been migrated there for more than 60 days (or whatever the time period is).

Comment: @animuson: Well, my vote is for deletion of the original on SO, but you're going to break a bunch of Internet links, and we should probably wait until the problem is fixed anyway.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, @animuson. The question was closed as not constructive on programmers, which is what triggered the migration rejection, if I read the timestamps correctly.

Comment: FWIW, I tried to put together a query at http://data.stackexchange.com/ to detect other cases of this, but based upon the schema, two accepted-answers does not seem to be possible. I'm guessing that dupe-accepted-answers occur in a caching layer and that the fix probably involves invalidating the cache for the question & answers.