# Locked community wiki has two accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, migration, accepted-answer

Here is the post in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

On both Firefox and IE, I see two accepted answers, as shown in the screen capture below.

I assume it's the same problem as referenced by this meta question: [SU question 473143 has two accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147004/su-question-473143-has-two-accepted-answers)

I would have just flagged for moderator attention, but that feature appears to be unavailable for locked questions.

[image]

Comment: I find it hilarious that when two accepted answers are encountered, it doesn't then sort them by number of votes. I demand this bug be fixed!

Comment: Any idea how this happened?

Answer (score 2):

This crops up occasionally on old questions (the bug which caused it was fixed long ago). This particular one was probably complicated by its history, which involved a migration and lots of locking, unlocking, deletion and undeletion.

I've restored the migration history and removed the accept marks.

Comment: Now if only you guys could fix that migration notice using the name from the first migration rather than the second...

Comment: I consider blaming Robert a *feature*, @animuson.