# Two accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, accepted-answer, live-refresh

I saw the same problem as in this ([Two accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127792/two-accepted-answers)) post  on Math.SE. I want to pay attention on it, because it linked post is written that this bug has been yet fixed.

[image]

Quote comes from [Two accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127792/two-accepted-answers) :

> I noticed this anomaly after clicking the "load new answers" link [on
>   this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUAmd.png):
>
> As far as I can tell, this was caused by the following sequence of
>   events:
>
> 1. I loaded the question with one accepted answer and left the tab open for a while.
> 2. Meanwhile, a new answer was posted and the OP changed this to be the accepted answer.
> 3. I returned to the tab, noticed the "load new answers" banner, and clicked it.
> 4. The new answer got loaded, but now both were shown as accepted.
>
> Of course, refreshing the page fixes the issue.

Comment: You did not link the mentioned post.

Comment: I see only see one answer accepted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517691/point-p-lies-on-the-sphere-described-a-cube

Comment: Did you read linked by question ? It happens in live refresh ...

Comment: @Ty221 Put that in this post then.

Comment: @Joshc Has been Done

Comment: @Oded Just curious, but does the accepted-answer state get live-refreshed? As in, if you load a page that has an accepted answer, and that answer get unaccepted, would that state ever refresh automatically, or does it only refresh the vote counts?

Comment: @animuson - I would think you would need to refresh the whole page for that. The accept status is not live-refreshed. What happened here is a rather rare race. Not really worth fixing.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Oded:

> The accept status is not live-refreshed. What happened here is a
>   rather rare race. Not really worth fixing.

[Accepting two answers marked as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316568/215590) suggests that the symptoms described in this question are still occurring.

Comment: I think it *is* live-refreshed now.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog It wasn't for me 3 hours ago ;)