# Accepting two answers marked as solved

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, live-refresh

[image]

I noticed a small visual bug. You have the same page in two tabs, you accept an answer in one, you go to the other, someone posts an answer and you accept it. You go to the first tab, you click on the "you have recieved a new answer", and then you find that it has the marked as solved mark but the other answer still has it as well. I hope I've been clear enough.

**EDIT:** This is apparently a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199857/two-accepted-answers), but that said question is marked as `status-norepro` so it wasn't fixed, I'm confirming that that problem still exists to this day, 5 years later.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the browser?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199857/215590